# Sybase convert float to string

Tags: sql, sybase, type-conversion

I have a requirement to convert fields in `float` to `string`, with following restrictions

1. Need to truncate the results after 6 places after decimal point
2. Truncate any trailing zeros after decimal

For example:

1. 17.666655942234 ==> converted to string "17.666655"
2. 17.6  ==> converted to string "17.6" and not "17.600000"
3. 17.66  ==> converted to string "17.66"

I have tried the following, but fail for some of the above requirements and also not able to remove the zero's.

```
select 
CASE WHEN RIGHT(convert(VARCHAR, cast(cast(product_price as DECIMAL(28,6))  as float)),2) = ".0"
THEN LEFT(convert(VARCHAR, product_price),(CHAR_LENGTH(convert(VARCHAR(15), product_price))-2))
ELSE substring( convert(VARCHAR, cast(cast(product_price as DECIMAL(28,7))  as float)),1, charindex(".",convert(VARCHAR, cast(cast(product_price as DECIMAL(28,7))  as float)))+6) END 
from #TEMP
```

#### #TEMP data

```
id | product_price
-------------------
1  | 17.3435302323
2  | 17.700000000
3  | 17.60
4  | 19.0
```

I guess, I have complicated the query and a simpler version should exists.

I know this could be easily handled in high level language, but if this could be easily be accommodated in the query itself then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is easier way to do that on sybase.

This example works for me

```
declare @val float
declare @val2 float
select @val = 17.666655942234 
select @val2 = 17.66
select substring(convert(varchar(30),@val), 1, patindex('%.%',convert(varchar(30),@val)))+reverse(convert(varchar(30),convert(int,reverse(substring(convert(varchar(30),@val), patindex('%.%',convert(varchar(30),@val))+1,6))))) as Val,
       substring(convert(varchar(30),@val2), 1, patindex('%.%',convert(varchar(30),@val2)))+reverse(convert(varchar(30),convert(int,reverse(substring(convert(varchar(30),@val2), patindex('%.%',convert(varchar(30),@val2))+1,6))))) as Val2
```

solution with `varchar(15)`

```
declare @val numeric(10,5)
declare @val2 numeric(10,5)
select @val = convert(numeric(10,5),17.666655942234)
select @val2 = convert(numeric(10,5),17.66)
select convert(varchar(15),substring(convert(varchar(15),@val), 1, patindex('%.%',convert(varchar(15),@val)))+reverse(convert(varchar(15),convert(int,reverse(substring(convert(varchar(15),@val), patindex('%.%',convert(varchar(15),@val))+1,6)))))) as Val,
       convert(varchar(15),substring(convert(varchar(15),@val2), 1, patindex('%.%',convert(varchar(15),@val2)))+reverse(convert(varchar(15),convert(int,reverse(substring(convert(varchar(15),@val2), patindex('%.%',convert(varchar(15),@val2))+1,6)))))) as Val2
```

Comment: Yes it is working for me but there is one more constraint that i cannot use varchar more than 15 and after changing to varchar 15 it is not wokring for me can u please suggest something  ?

Comment: If you replace `convert(varchar(30),@val)` with `convert(varchar,@val)` will it work?

Comment: You can also convert `float` to `numeric(10,5)`, a edited the post.

Comment: I added `convert(varchar(15)...` try it now pls.